# Batch: Compare date strings

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory with the following files:

```
u_ex150518.log
u_ex150517.log
u_ex150516.log
...
```

I would like to

1. extract the date: `%YY%MM%DD` from the filename `u_ex%YY%MM%DD.log`
2. check if the string `%YY%MM%DD` is "greater", that is more recent than a particular date, e.g. `150101`

I only know that to extract a part of a string I could use `%var::~start,length` but i have no idea of how to do the rest.. and also how to do a for through the files of the directory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: This date could be entered using a set/p or accepted as a parameter if required
SET /a targetdate=150517
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\u_ex*.log") DO (
 IF /i "%%~na" gtr "u_ex%targetdate%" ECHO %%~na
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Sadly, you don't say what output you actually want. This produces the name-parts of the files later than the target date. If you want earlier, replace `gtr` with `lss`. if you want to include the target date use `geq` or `leq` for greater/less-than or equal.

The point is that your date format yymmdd auto-sorts and makes comparison easier.

Also note that in windows batch, a variable is accessed by `%varname%` not `%varname`, except for parameters (%0..%9) and metavariables (%%a)

Also I'm assuming you are referring to `cmd` batch, but you haven't tagged your question `cmd`, so perhaps you are using some other OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
if not exist log md log
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:a
set /p check=Enter date to check against in this format (YY-MM-DD):
set check=!check:-=!
    set LIST=
    for %%I in (*) do (
    set LIST=%%I
    ::isolate the date from the original file name
    set lo=!LIST:u_ex=!
    set log=!lo:.log=!
    ECHO --------------------------
    echo !log!
    ::separate into yy/mm/dd
    set yy=!log:~0,2!
    set mm=!log:~2,2!
    set dd=!log:~4,2!
    echo !yy!-!mm!-!dd! extracted from !LIST!
    echo !yy!-!mm!-!dd! extracted from !LIST! >>log\log.txt
    if !log! GTR !check! echo !LIST! is newer than !check!
    if !log! LSS !check! echo !LIST! is older than !check!
    if !log! GTR !check! echo !LIST! is newer than !check! >log\log.txt
    if !log! LSS !check! echo !LIST! is older than !check! >log\log.txt
    echo -------------------------
    )
pause
```

place in the same directory as your log files